# How to force vuejs to call `mounted()` method if url changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Vuejs not coming to `mounted` method if url changes from `user/:id` to `user`

I am using same template file `User.vue`

Its working if I go to `user/:id` then `other_page` and then `user`

Comment: can you add the codes?

Comment: please give me time its complected but I will surely updating my question with codes

Comment: Hi, I won't post this as an answer as it is possibly off topic, but have you tried using your mounted code into a function, then call this function in the render hook + setup a watcher on the route object